# XGBoost fit() custom eval_metric is not called. Why?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am passing a custom evaluation metric function to XGB fit(), but the Python API discards callable (i.e., custom) functions. Why?
How are we supposed to pass in this function? Or is this functionality not supported by the Python/Scikit API?

```
model = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=scale_pos_weight)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric=xgb_f1)
```

In sklearn.py (line 755):

```
def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, base_margin=None,
            eval_set=None, eval_metric=None,
            early_stopping_rounds=None, verbose=True, xgb_model=None,
            sample_weight_eval_set=None, callbacks=None):
...
        feval = eval_metric if callable(eval_metric) else None
        if eval_metric is not None:
            if callable(eval_metric):
                eval_metric = None           # <<<<<<<<<< If eval_metric is callable, it's discarded
            else:
                xgb_options.update({"eval_metric": eval_metric})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a deeper look into the source code your custom evaluation metric is indeed being used, in the code snippet that you posted above if you look at this line:

```
feval = eval_metric if callable(eval_metric) else None
```

your custom evaluation metric (which is a callable) is being assigned to this variable called `feval` which is then being passed on to the actual method, `train`, that does your fitting as done [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L820). And now when you look at the [docstring](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/306e38ff3145b559e3a7c67d071d8a4ced5f70a3/python-package/xgboost/training.py#L118) of the `train` method you can find that `feval` corresponds to `Customized evaluation function`. Since `xgboost` uses the term `feval` for referring to custom evaluation metric and `sklearn` uses the term `eval_metric`, the authors of xgboost retained the variable name as it is for ease of understanding and do this conversion internally.

Hops this helps!

Comment: I actually traced the code deeper than that, and the feval value disappears at some point and is not used. I can tell you for sure that my custom eval_metric function is not called. I put a both a print() and a break point in it and neither are getting hit. Do you have a sample code that's working for you that I could try?